# View Users Front End - php code

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, jdatabase

I am using http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer in order to place some custom php code in an article to display all my registered users in the front end of my Joomla 3.3 site. I am new to this so appreciate any help.

The code does work however it displays the users all in one long line with no breaks and is very difficult to read,

like this:

```
id|username|email|id|username|email|id|username|email|... etc
```

Can somebody explain how I take a new line after each user, for example:

```
id|username|email|<br>
id|username|email|<br>
id|username|email|<br>
```

I have tried adding `\n` and other variations in single and double quoted but it won't seem to make any difference.

My code is below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__users" ;
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
     echo $row->id.'|'.$row->username.'|'.$row->email;<br>
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with @Tim Wilkinson's answer, I would also use up to date coding standards for doing your database query like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
      ->select($db->quoteName('*'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<p>' . $row->id .'|'.$row->username.'|'.$row->email . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lodder, what is the advantage of doing it your way? It it safer code?

Comment: @johnny_s - This page will explain things for you ;) http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
echo $row->id.'|'.$row->username.'|'.$row->email.'<br>';
```